# 301 redirect using regular expression in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have suddenly been hit with hundreds of 404 crawl errors to pages which must have been on a previous site (though I thought I'd got them all...). It's a bit strange as I've never seen any page with index.php in it, yet all the errors start with index.php/xxxxx.

So, I want to do the following:

> redirect 301 index.php/`<wildcard>` http://www.example.com

in the `.htaccess` file.

Can someone tell me whether this is correct, and what I have to put in the `<wildcard>` place if it is? If this is incorrect, what is the code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a the Redirect directive in the htaccess file and do a simple regular expression assuming your site doesn't use /index.php/query/parameters like some PHP frameworks do.

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/(.+) http://www.mysite.com
```